# Safari 8: Delete key no longer deletes text inside the form fields

Tags: safari, macos

Since I upgraded to Yosemite and Safari 8 I have to press Ctrl+Delete or Shift+Delete to delete the text I typed in web forms. Nothing happens if I press Delete key by itself.

Is this just me, or someone else experiencing the same issue? Is there a fix?

I am using MBP's built-in keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else has this issue: the problem was with Click2Flash Safari extension. If you are experiencing a similar issue, try disabling all extensions and restarting Safari. You can also try disabling JavaScript to confirm that this is an extension related issue.

Removing Click2Flash and restarting resolved this issue for me.